# A question about UART communication

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart, microchip, serial-bus

Are there predefined keywords/codes that when sent from a pic to a computer running windows (UART) can elicit certain actions (like show a special pattern or open a picture on the screen) on the computer directly without requiring to program a special app to process the signals sent (like VB.net)?

Comment: There are codes with traditional meanings but nothing happens without appropriate software to recognize them, which would *not* typically be running by default on a modern PC.  Computer usage questions are off topic here.  Further as you've not even stated a specific goal, non-specific questions are off topic across the whole SE system.

Comment: downvote, because you are assuming that we know what operating system is being used on the computer and for assuming that we know what "certain actions" means

Comment: @jsotola I have edited the question

Comment: it seems like you are not asking a direct question ... if you wish to display a picture on the screen, then say so ... do not ask some vaguely related question

Comment: instead of asking `is there a road between Glasgow and London?`, ask `how do i get from Glasgow to London by road?`

Comment: Modern computers don't have UARTs, they have USB. If your PIC can do USB then it could act as a [HID device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device)  and do anything the user could do with the keyboard or mouse.  Or you could use a USB adapter that converts serial data to keyboard input. https://www.aitronic.de/en/serial-hid-adapter

Comment: @BruceAbbott I have done that project before but I would have to program a serial port reader to process my signals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there aren't.  If nothing else, it would be a security nightmare for anyone who used serial comms to connect to other systems.

Exception:  Some systems allow you to use the serial port as the "console".  If that's the case, then you get access to a command prompt, at which you can enter any command you like.